# Is there something or There is something?

Tags: questions, syntactic-analysis

If I want to make a question, shall I start using `Is there` or `There is`?

For example I want to say: `Is there a way to calculate energy produced by the combustion of an hydrocarbon?` but I am not sure if I have to say `There is a way to calculate energy produced by the combustion of an hydrocarbon?`

Comment: @HotLicks, sorry, I am not sure if you are telling me a joke... are you asking serious?

Comment: You have failed to provide any context for your two two-word segments.  They can be used many ways.  You need to write a better question.

Comment: @HotLicks ¿? Could you explain better?

Comment: You can't just ask if you use "is there" to ask a question.  You need to provide a reasonably complete example of the sort of question you wish to ask.

Comment: Absent any differences in intonation (which are represented in print by the question mark), your example "Is there a way ..." is asking a question, while "There is a way ..." is making an assertion.  But intonation can make a big difference, especially for the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to state the normal, simple case in basic English and move on to subtleties​ later. In simple English inversion turns a statement into a question.

> **There is a way to calculate energy.** (statement)
>
> **Is there a way to calculate energy?** (question)

Those are the normal ways to do things, and if you stick to that formation you will never be incorrect or misunderstood.

The subtleties arise because it is possible to turn the statement into a question in spoken English with voice inflection. In written English you can simulate that by adding a question mark and using context, but you run the risk of being misunderstood. The failure to invert when asking a question is a common error among non-native English speakers, and so you risk people assuming that your English is poor. The linked questions discuss how and when to write the uninverted form of the question in advanced writing.

In formal, factual English you should stick to the structures above.

Comment: Great, thank! I have learned this in school but wasn't sure.